# Recover Data from External 1TB HDD

Tags: mount, hard-drive, data-recovery, external-hdd

I'm currently running Ubuntu 13.04 and my external hard drive no longer seems to mount. I've tried plugging it into a Windows OS Laptop and it comes up with a corruption error when trying to access the disk.

On Ubuntu I can only view the disk using gparted but again cannot access any data etc.

What is the best method for trying to recover this data? Most of it I have backed up but there are some folders which aren't, so ideally I would like to be able to recover the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you don't use the drive, and try [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).  Also if you have room on another drive, you can try using [dd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd).

**Note**: Keep in mind, that when it comes to data recovery nothing is guaranteed.  Also it can be a time consuming project, so be patient.

Comment: I will give TestDisk a go. How long will it take to scan the disk do you think? 1TB disk with about 70GB used up on the disk

Comment: Update after scanning with testdisk it found no partitions etc so I tried photorec instead and managed to recover hopefully the things that I need, says it will take 54hrs! I may already have enough to stop it and just keep what has been recovered!

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a better answer than this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: This also helped with the photorec option so thanks for this link. Unfortunately I cant vote up due to my reputation being under 15!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a drive cloning utility to move your data to a new harddrive. Many of them have the ability to clone a failing harddrive by skipping the bad sectors. You can create and .img file of the drive or clone it directly to another drive. [Hirens Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/) has a cloning utility, as well as some other stuff that might come in handy.

Comment: Ok will also look into that, cheers. Also if a disk has 4 bad sectors does that mean its basically broken or going that way?

Comment: I wouldn't trust it with important data.