# Recovering data from external unmountable HDD

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, data-recovery

I have an external "LaCie Rugged Mini 2TB USB 3.0" HDD that decided to suddenly not mount anymore. The issue is that I have some very sensitive data on it that I desperately need to recover somehow. It's not a lot it should be less than 50 GB.

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

gives me this output for the device

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 1,8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 93DC1AFA-6764-4C5F-B3FE-216C1758C29B

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1          40     409639     409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sdc2      409640 1954241295 1953831656 931,7G Apple Core storage
/dev/sdc3  1954241296 1954503439     262144   128M Apple boot
/dev/sdc4  1954503440 3906766983 1952263544 930,9G Microsoft basic    data
```

Any help with this is highly appreciated!

Edit:

I ran `dmesg` and the output is really long but the parts related to the HDD are:

```
[94084.906901] usb 2-1.2.1.1: reset high-speed USB device number 19 using ehci-pci
[94085.048270] scsi host7: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler success
[95373.504410]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 sdc3 sdc4
[95394.578567] usb 2-1.2.1.1: USB disconnect, device number 19
[95394.579116] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[95394.816034] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[95399.967851] usb 2-1.2.1.1: new high-speed USB device number 33 using ehci-pci
[95400.109601] usb 2-1.2.1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=059f, idProduct=106b
[95400.109603] usb 2-1.2.1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[95400.109604] usb 2-1.2.1.1: Product: Rugged Mini USB 3.0
[95400.109605] usb 2-1.2.1.1: Manufacturer: LaCie
[95400.109606] usb 2-1.2.1.1: SerialNumber: 00000000757cc736005a
[95400.111359] scsi host6: uas
[95400.112359] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     LaCie    Rugged Mini USB3 1053 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[95400.184465] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[95400.184756] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[95401.195809] ...ready
[95403.250786] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[95403.250788] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[95403.252128] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[95403.252130] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[95403.252625] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[95403.310523]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4
[95403.754026] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Edit 2:

I tried to do `sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdc4 /media/your_username/rescue` but I got `mount: /dev/sdb4 is already mounted or /media/nrko/rescue busy` and if I `umount /dev/sdb4` I get `umount: /dev/sdb4: not mounted`

Edit 3:

Booting from Windows and performing a `chkdsk /f e:` fixed the corrupted drive and I was able to back up my data!

Comment: Was the data registered with Ubuntu? It's often better to try to recover data using tools for the same O.S. that wrote them. Anyway, Linux options are often through testdisk: http://askubuntu.com/questions/334512/recover-data-from-external-1tb-hdd?rq=1

Comment: What filesystem was it using?

Comment: Connect the disk, immediately run `dmesg` to see the system's complaint.

Comment: 1 TB partition, the Apple one was created through OS X and was encrypted as well using the system's software. I'm not really interested in that one. The partition that interests me is the Microsoft basic data one, which was created through OS Windows 10 as exFAT if I remember correctly, because I wanted it to be readable and writable across mac/linux/windows. I downloaded testdisk and I am currently analyzing the disk. What else should I do? I really appreciate all the help you are providing.

Comment: Could you do a `sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdc4 /media/your_username/rescue`. If it complains that directory rescue doesn't exist, then `sudo mkdir /media/your_username/rescue/` and try again.

Comment: @heynnema I just did that but I got this `mount: /dev/sdb4 is already mounted or /media/nrko/rescue busy`  But I can't see the HDD in the file manager anywhere.

Comment: It's sdc4, not sdb4.

Comment: If you have Windows, you could boot Windows and do a `chkdsk /f d:` changing "d" to the appropriate drive letter. This will check the file system.

Comment: I unplugged it and plugged it again and it changed to sdb4. I will try with Windows as well.

Comment: Thank you so much @heynnema !! performing a disk check from Windows was able to fix the corrupted drive and I am now currently backing up the data. Can you perhaps make a full answer to this thread with your comment so I can accept it and give you some good rep, just so I can return the favor? Also can you recommend what to do with the external HDD now? Completely format it and check it entirely? I also want to have 1 partition on it that I can share between linux/windows/mac was exFat not the correct one for data safety? Or what exactly could have caused the corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

Since you're primarily concerned about the data on /dev/sdc4, the exFAT partition, do this:

- connect the drive to a machine running Windows (may be the same machine)
- note what drive letter it takes
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `chkdsk /f d:`, changing the "d" to the correct drive letter
- retest the drive under Ubuntu

The drive probably got corrupted because it was improperly dismounted, or unplugged without dismounting first.

The most compatible format to share data between Windows/Ubuntu/Mac would be NTFS. On the Mac, you will need a 3rd party NTFS driver... Paragon makes one. See https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/.